# How do i alter my Current code to read directly from the IDR register

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, gpio

Modify the code for **ReadJoystick()** to read the **IDR register** directly for the ports associated
with the joystick inputs. The aim is to minimise the number of reads to the register. The code in
the template makes an individual call for each of the inputs pins, even though some of the pins are
on the same ports.
You can refer to the HAL code for inspiration. Use the defined values in the HAL for addressing
registers rather than creating new ones.

Example Code Given to Me

```
GPIO_PinState HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    GPIO_PinState bitstatus;
     /* Check the parameters */
    assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN(GPIO_Pin));
if ((GPIOx->IDR & GPIO_Pin) != (uint32_t)GPIO_PIN_RESET)
{
    bitstatus = GPIO_PIN_SET;
}
else
{
    bitstatus = GPIO_PIN_RESET;
}
return bitstatus;
```

}

---

**Code I require to Alter**

// REPLACE THE FOLLOW CODE WITH YOUR SOLUTION

```
uint8_t
ReadJoystick ()
{
  uint8_t JoystickPosition = 0;

  // Get current joystick value
  if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (JOY_A_GPIO_Port, JOY_A_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
  {
    JoystickPosition = 'L';
  }
  else if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (JOY_B_GPIO_Port, JOY_B_Pin) == 
GPIO_PIN_RESET)
  {
JoystickPosition = 'U';
  }
  else if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (JOY_C_GPIO_Port, JOY_C_Pin) == 
 GPIO_PIN_RESET)
   {
     JoystickPosition = 'D';
   }
   else if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (JOY_D_GPIO_Port, JOY_D_Pin) == 
 GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    {
      JoystickPosition = 'R';
    }
   else if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin (JOY_CTR_GPIO_Port, JOY_CTR_Pin) == 
GPIO_PIN_RESET)
  {
    JoystickPosition = 'C';
  }

  return JoystickPosition;
 }
```

So I Understand that my current code is reading each pin although i've been asked to alter this to read directly from the IDR register. I'm really new to embedded systems programming and just looking for someone to guide me with altering this code

Comment: At https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic you will find it states:  _"Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it."_.  You have provided neither, which makes it look like a homework cheat rather then a legitimate request for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Before I post my solution I need to advice against reading from registers directly. Whoever is giving you this task wants to be a smart-ass and thinks that calling the HAL_GPIO_ReadPin function results in some kind of unbearable overhead which is most definitely not true. In fact, if all the port defines from JOY_A_GPIO_Port to JOY_CTR_GPIO_Port are different and optimizations are turned on, then the compiler is very likely to produce optimal code. Furthermore replacing the function call with direct register reads reduces the reuse-ability of the application code.

Anyhow, lets apply some changes...

Lets start off with a 1:1 translation which uses direct register access:

```
uint8_t ReadJoystick() 
{
  uint8_t JoystickPosition = 0u;

  // Get current joystick value
  if ((JOY_A_GPIO_Port->IDR & JOY_A_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    JoystickPosition = 'L';
  else if ((JOY_B_GPIO_Port->IDR & JOY_B_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    JoystickPosition = 'U';
  else if ((JOY_C_GPIO_Port->IDR & JOY_C_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    JoystickPosition = 'D';
  else if ((JOY_D_GPIO_Port->IDR & JOY_D_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    JoystickPosition = 'R';
  else if ((JOY_CTR_GPIO_Port->IDR & JOY_CTR_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    JoystickPosition = 'C';

  return JoystickPosition;
}
```

In case you haven't fully understood the code yet:

- xxx_Port->IDR reads the input data register for the whole port
- A bitwise & masks the input and gives us only the specific pin we are
  looking for

As I mentioned before this is not going to bring any performance improvements whatsoever.

However we might improve the code a little if some of the port defines are equal and point to the same memory address. In practice this is common because embedded designers are usually keen to join IO pins of an external device on a single port. E.g. lets assume JOY_A_GPIO_Port == JOY_B_GPIO_Port, then we could read the input data register of this port just once into a local variable like this:

```
uint8_t ReadJoystick() 
{
  uint8_t JoystickPosition = 0;

  // Read input data register for AB once
  uint32_t ab_port = JOY_AB_GPIO_Port->IDR;

  // Get current joystick value
  if ((ab_port & JOY_A_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    JoystickPosition = 'L';
  else if ((ab_port & JOY_B_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    JoystickPosition = 'U';
  else if ((JOY_C_GPIO_Port->IDR & JOY_C_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    JoystickPosition = 'D';
  else if ((JOY_D_GPIO_Port->IDR & JOY_D_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    JoystickPosition = 'R';
  else if ((JOY_CTR_GPIO_Port->IDR & JOY_CTR_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET)
    JoystickPosition = 'C';

  return JoystickPosition;
}
```

This effectively just saved us one register read. Of course the more joystick pins there are on a single port the better.

/edit
ST provides an alternative function for reading a whole port in their "LL" library:

```
__STATIC_INLINE uint32_t LL_GPIO_ReadInputPort(GPIO_TypeDef *GPIOx)
{
  return (uint32_t)(READ_REG(GPIOx->IDR));
}
```